# Getting the not matched rows from tbl_customer when left join with tbl_Linked table

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables:

tbl_Customer

```
   CustID   Name   Industry
   101       a       2 
   102      b       1
   103      c       2
   104      d       2
```

tbl_linked :

```
Cust1      Cust2     Industry

101         103           2
```

For customerID 101 based on Industry (id=2) I get linked customer directly from
tbl_Linked is 103

if I want matched customer for CustID 101, then there are two matching on Industry = 2, they are 103 and 104. However since 103 is already linked in the link table i.e. tbl_Linked, then I should get matched as 104 only.

Hope this helps in understanding my problem, else pls let me know.

To get matched, I used joins *left join, but it is still giving me either 103 & 104 or none.

I want to get all matched first, then check in link table if any of them already linked, and filter those out and need rest as matched.

Comment: Please clarify your join condition. Do you want on join tbl_Customer.CustID = tbl_linked.Cust1 AND tbl_Customer.Industry = tlb_linked.Industry?

Comment: What have you tried to do this? Can you add your current attempt of a `SELECT` statement to your question?

Comment: select * from tbl_customer left join tbl_linked on (tbl_customer.custid=tbl_linked.cust1) or (tbl_customer.custid=tbl_linked.cust2) where (tbl_customer.custid<>tbl_linked.cust2) or (tbl_customer.custid<>tbl_linked.cust1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
SELECT t2.CUSTID 
FROM tbl_Customer t1
INNER JOIN tbl_Customer t2 
ON (t1.Industry = t2.Industry)
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_linked t3 
ON (t1.CUSTID = t3.Cust1 AND t2.CUSTID = t3.Cust2  AND t1.Industry = t3.Industry)
WHERE t1.CustID <> t2.CustID
AND t1.CustID = 101
AND t3.Cust2 IS NULL
```